# Плавное перемещение меню сайта

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Я пытаюсь сделать такой же эффект как у bootstrap когда листаешь страничку вверх-вниз и меню, которое находится вверху, перемещается вместе со скроллированием.

В принципе я сделал этот эффект, однако есть одно но - видно, иногда, как дергается эта менюшка в след за скроллированием, поэтому вопрос - как сделать что бы меню перемещалось плавно???

Вот мой js код:

```js
window.onscroll = function()
      {
        let menu = document.getElementById("NavbarMenu");
        menu.style.position = "absolute";
        menu.style.width = "100%";
        let scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        menu.style.top = scrolled + "px";
      }
```

Я знаю что у бутстрапа есть такой эффект, однако я использую bootstrap4 и этот эффект не работает в IE10 и ниже, поэтому я хочу сделать его сам с помощь js.

Answer (score 5):

Можно задать классу меню свойства

```
 position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0
```

Либо,

```
   position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0;
```

Зачем из JS это делать, я пока не понял.

Comment: Боже, прячусь от стыда, это было так просто, а меня в js понесло....спасибо!